# react-native-code-push + react-native-sentry don't update correctly js

Tags: javascript, react-native, sentry, react-native-code-push

I use Sentry + code push in ma project but my push code install is causing problem....
On a version in test flight, the modifications were not applied correctly (while without push code everything is ok).

Can i with sentry install it this way:

first I "init" my code push like this:

```
export const intiCodePush = () => {
  const env = getEnvVars()
  codePush.sync({ deploymentKey: env?.codePushKey });
};
```

And I use it in my App.tsx like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    intiCodePush();
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }, []);
```

Always in my App.tsx I set some options for code push:

```
const codePushOptions = { checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_START };
```

And I wrap my App with Sentry and code push like this:

```
export default Sentry.wrap(codePush(codePushOptions)(App));
```

Is it good for you?